# C++ Eclipse: Binary Search Tree node->data = variable doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

The build is successful but the runtime stops at

node->data = bid;

in the following function. So the output prints out successfully up to "Loading CSV file 888" cout statement. I'm not sure what is preventing it from running that code.

```
void BinarySearchTree::Insert(Bid bid) {
    // FIXME (2a) Implement inserting a bid into the tree
cout << "Loading CSV file 333" << endl;
Node* node = root;
cout << "Loading CSV file 888" << endl;
node->data = bid;
cout << "Loading CSV file 777" << endl;
if (root == NULL){
    //root->data = bid;
//root->left = 0;
//root->right = 0;
root = node;
node->left = NULL;
node->right = NULL;
cout << "Loading CSV file 444" << endl;
}
else
{
cout << "Loading CSV file 666" << endl;
Node* cur;
    cur = root;
    while (cur != NULL){
      if (strToDouble2(node->data.bidId) < strToDouble2(cur->data.bidId)){
         if (cur->left == NULL){
           cur->left = node;
           cur = NULL;
         }
         else{
           cur = cur->left;
         }
      }
      else
         if (cur->right == 0){
           cur->right = node;
           cur = NULL;
         }
         else{
           cur = cur->right;
         }
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    cout << "Loading CSV file 5555" << endl;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the tree is empty, so `root` is a null pointer, and so is `node` since `node = root;`.

Starting out by storing the value to insert in the root node is pretty odd.
If you're adding a node, the code should say `new Node` somewhere, and the inserted value should be in that node.

Figuring out where to create it left as an exercise.